# Regular expression doesn't capture elements as expected

Tags: php, regex

I have a regular expression that should capture 4 elements but it is only capturing 3. Here is the code

```
<?php

$re = '/<input.+>(.*)</m';
$str = '    <input type="radio" name="562" value="1" onclick> turtle.show() <br>
<input type="radio" name="562" value="2"> turtle.showLocation() <br>
<input type="radio" name="562" value="3"> turtle.showDirection()  <br>
<input type="radio" name="562" value="4"> turtle.showturtle() <br><input type="hidden" id="ans562" value="4">';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

https://3v4l.org/YY20a

Comment: Whats the intended outcome, and whats it doing you don't like? Show some example in/out.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this regular expression - in lazy/ungreedy mode:

```
$re = '/<input(?:\s.*)?>([^<]*)</mU';
```